# Error when running mle2 function (bbmle)

Tags: r, mle

I am receiving the following error when running the `mle2()` function from the `bbmle` package in R:

> some parameters are on the boundary: variance-covariance calculations based on Hessian may be unreliable

I am trying to understand if this is due to a problem with my data or an issue with calling the function properly. Unfortunately, I cannot post my real data, so I am using a similar working example of the same sample size.

The custom `dAction` function I am using is a softmax function. There have to be upper and lower bounds on the optimization so I am using the L-BFGS-B method.

```
library(bbmle)
set.seed(3939)

### Reproducible data
dat1 <- rnorm(30, mean = 3, sd = 1)
dat2 <- rnorm(30, mean = 3, sd = 1)
dat1[c(1:3, 5:14, 19)] <- 0
dat2[c(4, 15:18, 20:22, 24:30)] <- 0

### Data variables
x <- sample(1:12, 30, replace = TRUE)
pe <- dat1
ne <- dat2

### Likelihood
dAction <- function(x, a, b, t, pe, ne, log = FALSE) {
  u <- exp(((x - (a * ne) - (b * pe)) / t))
  prob <- u / (1 + u)

  if(log) return(prob) else return(-sum(log(prob)))
}

### Fit
fit <- mle2(dAction,
            start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, t = 0.1),
            data = list(x = x, pe = pe, ne = ne),
            method = "L-BFGS-B",
            lower = c(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, t = 0.1),
            upper = c(a = 10, b = 1, t = 10))

Warning message:
In mle2(dAction, start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, t = 0.1), data = list(x = x,  :
  some parameters are on the boundary: variance-covariance calculations based on Hessian may be unreliable
```

Here are the results for `summary()`:

```
summary(fit)
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle2(minuslogl = dAction, start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, t = 0.1), 
    method = "L-BFGS-B", data = list(x = x, pe = pe, ne = ne), 
    lower = c(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, t = 0.1), upper = c(a = 10, b = 1, 
        t = 10))

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(z)
a      0.1         NA      NA    NA
b      0.1         NA      NA    NA
t      0.1         NA      NA    NA

-2 log L: 0.002048047 

Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(object@vcov)) : NaNs produced
```

And the results for the confidence intervals

```
confint(fit)
Profiling...

  2.5 %    97.5 %
a    NA 1.0465358
b    NA 0.5258828
t    NA 1.1013322

Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(diag(object@vcov)) : NaNs produced
2: In .local(fitted, ...) :
  Non-positive-definite Hessian, attempting initial std err estimate from diagonals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't entirely understand the context of your problem, but:

The issue (whether it is a real problem or not depends very much on the aforementioned context that I don't understand) has to do with your constraints.  If we do the fit without the constraints:

```
### Fit
fit <- mle2(dAction,
            start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, t = 0.1),
            data = list(x = x, pe = pe, ne = ne))
            ## method = "L-BFGS-B",
            ## lower = c(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, t = 0.1),
            ## upper = c(a = 10, b = 1, t = 10))
```

we get coefficients that are below your bounds.

```
coef(fit)
         a          b          t 
0.09629301 0.07724332 0.02405173
```

If this is correct, at least one of the constraints is going to be active (i.e. when we fit with lower bounds, at least one of our parameters will hit the bounds - in fact, it's all of them). When fits are on the boundary, the simplest machinery for computing confidence intervals (Wald intervals) doesn't work. However, this doesn't affect the profile confidence interval estimates you report above. These are correct - the lower bounds are reported as `NA` because the lower confidence limit is at the boundary (you can replace these by 0.1 if you like).

If you didn't expect the optimal fit to be on the boundary, then I don't know what's going on, maybe a data issue.

Your log-likelihood function is not wrong, but it's a little confusing because you have a `log` argument that returns the negative log-likelihood when `log=FALSE` (default) and the likelihood when `log=TRUE`. Before I realized that, I rewrote the function (I also made it a little more numerically stable by doing computations on the log scale wherever possible).

```
dAction <- function(x, a, b, t, pe, ne) {
  logu <- (x - (a * ne) - (b * pe)) / t
  lprob <- logu - log1p(exp(logu))
  return(-sum(lprob))
}
```

Comment: I am following a model described in a paper. In the paper, the estimates for a, b, and t are discretized in units of 0.1 over the lower and upper ranges I specified above. The true lower bound for the variables is actually 0 but when I entered it in the function I got an error. So I decided to move the lower bound up to the next unit up which would be 0.1. So a value of less than 0.1 is not exactly unexpected... but I'm not sure how to deal with discretizing the output other than rounding to the nearest 0.1. If I did this, a, b, and t would all have the same value.

Comment: Hard to know without more information. What is the real purpose of the discretization?  Was it just for computational reasons (e.g. they were searching over the grid, or part of the downstream computation involves integrating over a volume, or ...) ? Are your data in the same units/range as there? Can you give the reference?

Comment: I ran the function without bounds on my own data (no discretization) and got similar results. The estimates for a, b, and t are so close to the boundary that if I run it through my original function (before log transformation) it produces a very large value for `u` and `prob <- u / (1+ u)` therefore asymptotically approaches 1. The probability is just 1 for everything which is definitely not right. I know this is leaving the scope of my question now but I would appreciate any advice on where to go from here. Thanks for your time and help.